# divだとfloat解除されるのに、spanだとされないのはなぜですか？

Tags: css, html5

`div`に`clear:left`を書くとfloat解除されるのに、
`span`だとされないのはなぜですか？

**[html]**

```
<img src="images/001.png" alt="">

    <!-- <div id="study_001"> -->
    <span id="study_001">
    <span id="margin">margin</span><span id="border">border</span><span id="padding">padding</span>
    </span>
    <!-- </div>だとfloat解除される！ -->
```

**[css]**

```
img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#study_001{
  clear: left;
}

#margin{
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  background: #f98;
}

#border{
  border-left: 3px #fff solid;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

#padding{
  background: #498;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
```

spanの場合（解除されない）
[image: spanの場合]

divの場合（解除される）
[image: divの場合]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

直接的には[`clear`プロパティ](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear)は

> *Applies to:*     block-level elements

とブロック要素にしか適用されないからです。

論理的にもブロック要素の開始位置を下にずらす機能です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力] → [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここでもしブロック要素の中間部分のインライン要素に対して`clear`を指定したとして、どのようなレイアウトを期待されますか？ …と考えると`<span>`要素で`clear`が機能しないのは適切かと。